Where are shutoff valves required for a natural gas line serving an outdoor grill?
I'll be branching a 3/4" line serving a garage heater to also serve a gas grill on my patio, at an existing capped tee. It'll be reduced to 1/2" before exiting the building. Where will I need to add valves for the new branch?

Just downstream of the tee? The tee is currently downstream of only the main shutoff just inside the building, in the same unfinished room.
Just before exiting the building? The wall penetration will be about 20 feet downstream of the tee in an adjacent room with a suspended ceiling.
Outside, at the wall penetration? I might run beyond that about 10 feet under a three-season porch floor.
Outside, at the iron pipe termination? From there it'll be the flex hose to the grill.
What if I opt to set up two termination points outside? Would I need one valve, two, or none?


You need a valve right before every convenience (quick disconnect) or flex tube.
You can add the extra valve inside but you still have to add the other ones outside right where the flexible tube starts. I have an extra valve on the inside I cut off so that kids can't turn on the gas outside.
See NPFA code 9.6.5 and 9.6.5.1:

Each appliance connected to a piping system shall have an accessible, approved manual shutoff valve with a nondisplaceable valve member, or a listed gas convenience outlet. Appliance shutoff valves and convenience outlets shall serve a single appliance only.
The shutoff valve shall be located within 6 feet (1829 mm) of the appliance it serves. Where a connector is used, the valve shall be installed upstream of the connector. A union or flanged connection shall be provided downstream from the valve to permit removal of appliance controls.


My convenience valve was about 5 feet upstream of the branch point, because the branch point was not easily accessible (was verbally told by inspector that any convenience valve has to be easily accessible). Inspector had no issue, only that the whole system was to be open during the static pressure test (and capped after the valves/quick disconnect & flex removed).

I created an account with NFPA, https://www.nfpa.org/, they give you access to view to standards.  NFPA9. 54 is for (Natural) Gas.
The access is weird because half of 9.6 is under 9.7, its just tied to the page (and you have to click 9.7 as you can't forward page from the 9.6 start page).
in 9.6  one shutoff per a appliance and 6 foot before appliance.  7.7 will have you look at the quick disconnect instructions (which should always CYA themselves in case they fail open).  Assume that your indoor valve doesn't have 6 feed direct access to the quick disconnect.

The free access to 54 won't let you copy out.

Thank you. I've added some of the code you referenced, but I wasn't sure what part of 7.7 was important with respect to shutoff valves. If you want that added, please clarify.

Sure, the 7.7 where it says to refer to quick disconnect installation instructions to keep in code.    I took an example of the dorman 1/2 quick disconnect instructions.       12. In addition to the main gas supply shut-off valve, an approved accessible manual gas shut-off valve MUST BE installed
upstream of the gas connector (within 6 feet of the equipment it serves). .....it's almost circular  logic but it pretty much refers to the same 6 ft req the earlier ones do.
